# tomcat 7 installation on ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

I recently upgraded to **Ubuntu 12.04LTS** and installing **Tomcat 7** but got following errors:

```
root@me:/# sudo apt-get install tomcat7 tomcat7-docs tomcat7-examples tomcat7-admin -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
tomcat7 : Depends: tomcat7-common (>= 7.0.26-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
tomcat7-admin : Depends: tomcat7-common (>= 7.0.26-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
tomcat7-docs : Depends: tomcat7-common (>= 7.0.26-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
tomcat7-examples : Depends: tomcat7-common (>= 7.0.26-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 15):

Apparently you need to remove `tomcat6-common` before installing tomcat7 due to some conflict.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/173981/installing-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-server-12-04.

Comment: Thank you Olivier.Roger,
It was because of tomcat6-common,

Comment: Man @Olivier.Roger that's pretty harsh not getting selected as best answer on this one!

Answer (score 4):

You can better download the package from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) and unpack it and use it.